# Call overridden C# method from C++ managed code

Tags: c#-4.0, managed-c++

I have C# public class with

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Do(int a1);
    public int Do(string a1);
}
```

In my C++ managed code I want to call the 2nd method with a `string` parameter.

```
//.cpp
...
MyClass^ cl = ...;
System::String^ var = gcnew System::String("value");
cl->Do(var);
```

And it fails with

> cannot convert param 1 from string to int

How can I call the 2nd method with the `string` parameter?

Comment: This should work. Maybe the problem is somewhere else. Can you open a new Console Project in C# and access the method from there?

Comment: The only reasonable explanation is that the C++/CLI compiler is using an old version of the C# assembly.  Use project references to avoid a mishap like this.

Comment: i'm using the same PC and the same VS to build C# library and C++ library.